# Set up remote camera monitoring on Android OS without user input

Tags: android, mobile, android-camera2, rooted-device

I'm developing a personal project app (NOT for Play Store) to run on an old pixel phone I have. Here are my requirements

1. On boot, I want to automatically launch my app
2. The app should open a live camera feed and collect images at some interval
3. The app should stay alive indefinitely until a user explicitly kills it
4. All this needs to happen with NO user input

Nice to haves, but NOT required

5. The app should be able to function without the screen on

Now, I've successfully rooted my device to remove as many hurdles as I can. I got my app to launch on BOOT_COMPLETED, etc. But I'm hitting walls with the camera. I know the camera is not allowed to run in a background service. I was considering trying to force my app to be a system app, but I'm not sure if that let's me use the camera in this way either. The other option is to run the app in the foreground, but that requires a user to explicitly allow it to run continuously or else the OS kills it. But this will potentially trigger and run when I'm away, so I won't be there to hit play.

This is all like "spying app 101" stuff so that's probably why Android has put up so many roadblocks. But this isn't for other people. I have complete control of my device and will use it on my own property. I can do whatever custom ROMs people suggest, but I've not worked on any Android OS system code before so I'm hoping not to do that. However, if that's the only way, please let me know if you have any suggestions on where to start.

What is best way to achieve my high level goals here? Literally any architecture or strategy to do this is fine so long as it meets my requirements above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably better on https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=automate+camera 
given that you are rooted, and willing to do custom ROM. it may help to know if device will be plugged in all the time and if so to what (PC, just outlet).

Comment: Yes it will be plugged into power (outlet) but not a computer. Excellent will try there! Thank you

Comment: How frequently do you want images?  That will make a big difference.  There's different techniques for needing things to happen at different time intervals.

Comment: Super fascinating! Why would that matter? I'd like to run basic ML models / CV stuff, so I want a relatively fast frame rate, like 1 fps at least.